# Bokeh Server not working when deployed from windows server

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-server-2008-r2, bokeh

We are trying to execute bokeh server from a Windows Server. Everything looks fine. But when trying to reach the it from another device we get the following error in the web browser: "403: Forbidden".
Even though the bokeh server is executed allowing all ports and incoming IPs, we still get a message telling us that the host is not in the whitelist. This is the server output when executing bokeh and trying to reach it from another computer:

[image: What we get at server level when executing bokeh Server and try to reach the it from another computer.]

Every device is connected to local network.

I attach what we get when log level is in debug:

[image: Debug level logs]

Comment: Hi. To me, this question seems to be a better fit for [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Quickest would be for you to move it and as you probably want fast answers and you are more likely to get them there, I would move it myself.

Comment: can you set the global log level to `debug`? that will explicitly report the value of the hosts whitelist on startup. As an aside, I am not aware of any Bokeh devs that check that other site (we barely have time to try and follow SO) but there may be others there that can help, who knows.

Comment: As an aside I just tried this on two macs on a local network with the same config and it's working as expected. Are users hitting the bokeh server directly? Or are you using `autoload_server` to embed? If so, there may be additional config needed. Alternatively, perhaps there is an issue specific to windows.

Comment: @bigreddot Just hitting it directly. The thing is, it works when bokeh Server is deployed from a Raspberry Pi we use for fast prototyping and testing, and user can connect to it an visualize graphs. But when we proceed to do the same from a windows server the above problem arises. It is probably something related to the network and/or server's firewall I guess.

Comment: @jotasi I have included the debug logs.

Comment: I inlined the images for you but it would be a good idea to actually replace the images by the text that they put out...

Comment: OK so when I start a server similarly on OSX I see `Allowed Host headers: ['*']` whereas your output shows `Allowed Host headers: ["'*':80"]` which seems incorrect, and would explain why the host matching check is failing. Perhaps there is some windows-specific bug related to shell-quoting differences?. At this point I recommend making a bug report on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) with this SO post as a reference.

Comment: As an immediate workaround, and by way of getting more information, does specify the actual host/ip that clients will connect to (instead of `'*'`) work?

Comment: Actually, does `--host=*` (no quotes) work? I am not a windows person, but I have a suspicion this is down to command line escaping/quoting differences between windows in some way.

Comment: @bigreddot Thanks for the observation. It was a sintaxis issue. With no quotes it works! Your answer is correct but I do not know how to vote for it!

Comment: I'll add an answer below, now that we know the answer. Also, this merits, at a minimum, some documentation support. Can you open an issue on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) regarding all this?

Comment: @bigreddot Yes! I am going to do it, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference in how shell quoting works between platforms. On Windows, you need to do

```
--host=*
```

with no quotes around the asterisk.

Comment: Experimenting with the sintaxis based to the examples from de documentation, the main issue is that in Windows Prompt if you write `--host='*'` it considers the quotes. If `--host '*'` is used (with no equal sign) then there is no problem. The documentation may cause some confusion as in some parts arguments include `=`, and in other parts they do not.